# Overlay 4 circles on each corner of a square CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a Simon Says game that uses the flashing of colors as a memory game.
 I want to overlay 4 circles on each of the four corners of a background square (the square will be transparent in the final version).

I have attached an image [LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcs0s.png) of what I would like it to look like and I've included the HTML and CSS.

```css
.html {
    color: grey;
}

#green {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: black;
    /*position: relative;*/
    /*float: left;*/

}

#red {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: black;
}

#yellow {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: gold;
    border-color: black;
}

#blue {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: black;
}

#square {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: purple;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

#display {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

#controls {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

}

#Highscore {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#Currentscore {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#startButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#powerLight {
    background-color: red;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simon Memory Game</title>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div id="green"></div>
        <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>

        <div id="square">
            <div id="display">
                <div id="controls">
                    <div id="Highscore">00</div>
                    <button class="button" id="startButton">START</button>
                    <div id="Currentscore">00</div>
                    <div id="powerLight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `position:center`

Comment: I might be missing something, but it looks like you can set the parent to `position: relative;`. Then you can use `position: absolute;` on those 4 circles to get them where you wish.

Comment: @justDan Nope, you're right...this is basic positioning. The OP clearly hasn't researched this.

Answer (score 3):

As has been suggested, you can use absolute positioning in order to achieve what you want.

I have moved the circle divs into the #square div, as to my understanding we want to position the circles within that div.

Then you can use left, right, top and bottom to position them, as I have done in the example below.

```css
.html {
    color: grey;
}

.game {
    position: relative;
}

#green {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#red {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: red;
    border-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#yellow {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: gold;
    border-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#blue {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 75px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#square {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: purple;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

#display {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

#controls {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;

}

#Highscore {
    position: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#Currentscore {
    position: center;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#startButton {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#powerLight {
    background-color: red;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simon Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assignment-02.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div id="square">
            <div id="display">
                <div id="controls">
                    <div id="Highscore">00</div>
                    <button class="button" id="startButton">START</button>
                    <div id="Currentscore">00</div>
                    <div id="powerLight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="green"></div>
            <div id="red"></div>
            <div id="yellow"></div>
            <div id="blue"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assignment-02.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it a lot :)